# WeakMap и HTMLElement в DOM

Tags: javascript

Работа WeakMap понятна, но при попытке удалить узел из браузера в WeakMap этот же узел не удаляется.

Код примерно такой:

```
let weakList = new WeakMap(), /// Пусто
    element = $0; /// $0 для выделения любого элемента на странице

weakList.set(element, true);
console.log(weakList); /// Не пусто

element.remove();
element = null;
console.log(weakList); /// Не пусто
```

Как решить этот вопрос?

Comment: а там разве не `delete` вместо `remove` нужно?

Comment: @Roman это интерфейс DOM. delete для удаления объектов нативного js. remove для удаления узла из DOM

Answer (score 4):

Вы удаляете элемент, но не выбрасываете его из значения переменной.

```js
const map = new WeakMap();
let element = document.querySelector('span');
map.set(element,element.innerText);
console.log(map.get(element)); // элемент тут
element.remove();
console.log(map.get(element)); // всё ещё тут
element = null;
console.log(map.get(element)); // пропал!
```

```html
<p>
  Text1
  <span>
    Text2
  </span>
  Text3
</p>
```

Comment: Хмм. А что если обращаться к элементу напрямую и удалять узел вручную через консоль отладки? У меня не удаляется из набора вот код:

`let weakList = new WeakMap();
weakList.set($0, true);
/*удаляем через консоль*/
console.log(weakList); /// Не пусто`

Comment: Пока будет хоть одна ссылка на объект, gc не отчистит значение WeakMap. А без ссылки на объект, само собой ссылаться на значение бесполезно.

Comment: Не много не верно ваши предположения пример с низу element = null; его в нет в map но это ни очем не говорит

Comment: Я знаю механизм работы WeakMap, просто непонятно поведение. Мы удаляем узел? Удаляем! Переменной посредника нет? Нет. WeakMap пуст? Нет! Почему?

Comment: Я лишь указываю вам на то что искать null не верно :)

Comment: @AzizUmarov вы в своем ответе сами ищете null)

Comment: Суть в том, что WeakMap всегда пуст. По сути - это то же самое что и переменная с ссылкой на объект в значении. Удалил значение из переменной - к объекту больше нет доступа. Если объект остался, и его можно извлечь откуда-нибудь еще, то и переменную можно восстановить.

Comment: Я о том же примерами так прос100 не проверишь.

Comment: @MaximPro. Просто код `element.remove()` удаляет элемент из DOM, но не из `element` и в дальнейшем, можно выполнить `document.body.appendChild(element)` и элемент снова будет в DOM.

Comment: Пересмотрите мой пример, я добавил строчку с обнулением переменной посредника. Но WeakMap считает что элемент присутствует в памяти.

Answer (score 1):

Не много не так поскольку в данном случае его там нет тоже.

```js
const map = new WeakMap();
let element = document.querySelector('span');
map.set(element,element.innerText);
console.log(map.get(element)); // элемент тут
element = null;
console.log(map.has(element));
```

```html
<p>
  Text1
  <span>
    Text2
  </span>
  Text3
</p>
```

WeakMap нужно немного постараться чтобы сделать валидный пример.

Comment: Пересмотрите мой пример. Я обнуляю объект посредник, но WeakMap не пуста.

Comment: @MaximPro я своим ответом показываю что не всё так гладко как показано в предыдущем ответе

Comment: Так понимаю вопрос придется спрашивать на бугорном SO :)

Comment: `element = null;
console.log(map.has(element));` — точна такая же бессмысленная проверка как и в соседнем ответе

Comment: @AlexeyTen я в ответе указал бесмысленность предыдущего даже без удаления

Answer (score 0):

Никто никогда не обещал, что WeakMap очистится мгновенно. WeakMap всего лишь не будет мешать Garbage Collector-у убрать ненужные объекты.

Стандартом *специально* не предусмотрена возможность посмотреть что лежит внутри WeakMap, так что вывод `console.log(weakList)` это чистая самодеятельность браузера.

Более того, ваш вывод `weakList` в консоль добавил ссылку на объект (в консоли вы можете посмотреть его свойства и т.п.), так что GC его и не соберёт.

Comment: Отвечая на последний абзац, ваш тезис неверен. Я проверял в консоли этот код много раз и были случаи когда GC показывал в WeakMap пустую карту элементов. Все проверки были идентичными. И исходя того что я написал, я соглашусь с тем что WeakMap очистится не мгновенно.